# In which CefSharp version is WebRTC disabled by default?

Tags: c#, webrtc, cefsharp, disable

im using CefSharp for WinForms (Version 69.0.0) and I have troubles to disable webrtc to hide my ip & surf anon. After reading some threads, i found out that there are older versions of cefsharp, witch have WebRTC disabled by default.

**But which version is it?**

or do you know a way how to disable it?.. i tried it with these settings but it doesn't seem to work for this version.

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "https://212.62.95.45:1080");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.ip_handling_policy", "false");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled", "false");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled", "false");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.ip_handling_policy","disable_non_proxied_udp");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "0");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable_webrtc", "0");
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any older version that has webrtc disabled. Please edit your post and provide references to the web pages you are referring. Only some of the command line arguments you've tried are actually command line arguments, all the webrtc ones should be set as preferences see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/69/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/BrowserProcessHandler.cs#L74

Comment: Best you re-read the articles you are referring in more detail.

Comment: amaitland, there are just 3 threads on google with that topic. 

"The only reliable way to completely disable WebRTC is do private CEF build with GN_DEFINE [c]enable_webrtc=false[/c]." 

"If you don't want to rely on private builds or want enable/disable it dynamically"


https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=15194

Comment: Build a custom version of `CEF` if that's what you choose, it's difficult. Setting those preferences is trivial, that's what I'd be trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void FormMainLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
    {
        var rc = chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;

        rc.SetPreference("webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled", false, out _);
        rc.SetPreference("webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled", false, out _);
        rc.SetPreference("webrtc.ip_handling_policy", "disable_non_proxied_udp", out _);
        rc.SetPreference("browser.enable_spellchecking", false, out _);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to precise wy this should fix the issue ?

Comment: You can turn off WebRTC by pasting this code.